# Use iterating variable to check value of dict key?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

here is my code

```
tiles = ["  a  ", "  b  ", "  c  ", "  d  ", "  e  ", "  f  ", "  g  ", "  h  ", "  i  "]
check = {'0': False, '1': False, '2': False, '3': False, '4': False, '5': False,
         '6': False, '7': False, '8': False}

tile = input("Player 1: What tile?")

for index, z in enumerate(tiles):
    if int(tile) == index and ********:
        tiles[index] = str("xxxxx")
```

What I want to be able to do, is on line 8, check if tile is the same as index, and also check the value of the key(this part is the ********)

Basically I want to use the iterating variable `index` to request and check the value of the key that is the same as `index`. This might look like

```
if int(tile) == index and check[?index?] == False:
```

Please help and I am more than wiling to explain further as I am not very good at explaining these kind of things.

Comment: the keys in `check` are strings, but `index` in your for loop is going to be an int. Simply cast it to a string like `check[str(index)]`

Comment: Also it would be better if you convert the `tile` to `int` during the input itself rather than changing it to `int` on every iteration.

Comment: @Hamms thank you so much, this worked. I tried it before but I must of messed up and therefore ignored the possibility.

Comment: I don't see why you have a loop here. I _think_ that if (for example) the user enters `3` you want to change tile 3 from `"  d  "` to `"******"` if `check['3']` is currently `False`. And I assume you'd also want to change `check['3']` to `True` so that tile 3 can't be changed again unless you reset `check['3']` back to `False`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if int(tile) == index and not check[str(index)]:
```

There are chances that `tile` is already an integer (if you entered one). Keys of `check` are strings.

Comment: `tile` will only be an integer already if the OP is using Python 2, in which case they really should be using `raw_input` (which is equivalent to Python 3's `input`), not the potentially dangerous Python 2 `input` function.

Comment: I agree, use `raw_input` and then cast. Not the issue here, but always worth mentionning.

Comment: Don't compare directly to a Boolean literal; just use `not check[str(index)]` instead.

Comment: Done. Make this a beautiful code would be overkill, no? :)